# How I check continuity and differentiability of a map defined from $f:\Bbb{R}^2 \to\Bbb{R}^2$

Tags: derivatives, continuity, several-complex-variables

Consider the map $f:\Bbb{R}^2 \to\Bbb{R}^2$ defined by $f(x,y)=(3x-2y+x^2 , 4x+5y+y^2)$. Then how I find continuity and differentiability and directional derivative at $(0,0)$?

Comment: Plz help me how I solve this question with proper concept

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I don't know how to proceed this question, no idea plz tell me what is the concept about this question and how i will proceed this question?